# Linq just starting out

Tags: c#, linq, format

I'm just trying to teach myself how to use Linq. This is what I have

```
if (FileReceivers.Exists(t => t.FileName == filename))
{
    //I also want to do a c.Parent = proper FileReceiver
    FileReceivers.Where(t=>t.FileName == filename).First().Clients.Add(c);
}
else
{
    FileReceiver fr = new FileReceiver(filename);
    fr.Clients.Add(c);
    FileReceivers.Add(fr);
}
```

Any ideas how I would do this the right way? I don't really want to be using Linq to twice to grab the same thing, that would defeat the purpose. 
I would just like to know the proper way to format this.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to cache the results of the exists test, to prevent duplicate testing, however, exists != where. It's entirely possible that trying to cache would create a bottleneck exactly where you're trying to prevent that now.

Comment: @SLaks not a bad idea, but I'd like to learn Linq.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var fr = FileReceivers.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.FileName == filename);

if (fr == null) {
    fr = new FileReceiver(filename);
    FileReceivers.Add(fr);
}
fr.Clients.Add(c);
```

Comment: Nice, I like that. I also wasn't sure if when you queried if the result was referenced to the original object, so I was kind of scared to just pull it out and use it, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @kelton52: LINQ does not create new objects.  In fact, it would be utterly impossible for that to happen.

Comment: Not create a new object, a shallow copy is what I was referring to.

Comment: A shallow copy is also a new object.

Answer (score 0):

you could always pass the results of `t => t.FileName == filename` to an anonymous type and use that for later processing.